# How to run a thread continuously in java application, even when the window is minimised?

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable

I have a class that implements the 'Runnable' interface and has a thread running in it. But as soon as the window is minimised, the thread stops to run, and restarts on maximising the window, from the state which it had before minimising.
How should i ensure continuous running of a thread even if the window is minimsed?

Answer (score 4):

It's true for GUI thread.
You can create Worker thread to execute time-consuming tasks.